# DNS wildcard issue - after adding Cname record for google Domain verification

Tags: dns, verification, cname, wildcard-subdomain, google-domain-api

I've a domain, let's say `abcd.com`, For this domain,

We have a **wildcard** A record pointing to an IP say, `12.34.56.78`,

```
* => 12.34.56.78
```

So, all **subdomains of `abcd.com`** point to `12.34.56.78`. 
So, when I access `small.abcd.com`, it points to `12.34.56.78`. 
Then, we added a Cname record for Google domain verification of `small.abcd.com`,

```
eocjdrkdkoed.small => gv-f8ded7dfivfkdo.dv.googlehosted.com
```

For more information on this, go to `https://support.google.com/a/answer/47283?hl=en`

This caused a DNS error with **small.abcd.com**. That is, this url **small.abcd.com** is no longer accessible and it no longer points to **12.34.56.78**.
On nslookup, it says, **"Can't find small.abcd.com: No answer"**. 
Can anyone help me with this ? Is it an issue with my DNS provider or is it how DNS records work ?

**edit:**
The domain not working - small57.realizegoal.com.
Before, it used to point to xxx.xx.68.191. 
After adding DNS verification Cname record, it started failing.

Comment: No, since you chose to hide the information you want help to _publish for all the world to see_, nobody can help you. If you'd told us what domain has the problem, we could have had a look and maybe seen what's wrong.

Comment: I've mentioned what the domain is.

Comment: 5 years later I've run into the same issue; added some cnames for domain verification and resolution for the wildcard fails for one of the subdomains that we were using for an ingress.  Others still work but at least one fails.

@HiteshKumar were you able to solve this?